# Segmentation fault when handling characters

Tags: c

Fair warning, I am quite new to C, and am still very much a beginner with the language. This problem has stuck with me for a while and I thought someone here might be able to help.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int age;
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("You are %d years old \n", age);

    double gpa;
    printf("Enter your GPA: ");
    scanf("%lf", &gpa);
    printf("You're GPA is %lf \n", gpa);    

    char name[20];
    printf("Please enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Your name is %s \n", name);

    char grade;
    printf("Enter your grade: ");
    scanf("%s", &grade);
    printf("Your grade it %s \n ", grade);

return 0;
}
```

The problem lies in the 'grade' section, everything else works perfectly.
The output of the program with user input is

```
Enter your age: 3
You are 3 years old 
Enter your GPA: 4.5
You're GPA is 4.500000 
Please enter your name: Test
Your name is Test 
Enter your grade: B
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Hopefully someone here can help. All the best!

Comment: Hint: `grade` is a `char` not `char[]`.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &grade);` -->     `scanf("%c", &grade);`

Comment: Actually `scanf(" %c", &grade);` to handle the `'\n'` left from `name`.

Comment: This is why you compile with `-Wall -Wextra`

Answer (score 3):

Input for getting the input of grade would be

`scanf(" %c",&grade);`

The issue arises because the grade is a char variable, not a `char` array.

`char` -> `%c`

`char` array(aka String in C) -> `%s`

Comment: Thanks , I forgot about the \n being left by %s before, I did mean `scanf(" %c",&grade);`. Will edit and fix it .

Comment: Now that's what will keep the input for grade from being skipped! To make it a truly helpful answer, you could explain what is happening with the `"%s" `and leaving the `'\n'` in `stdin` unread and without the `" %c"` the `'\n'` will be taken as the input for `grade`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get `segmentation fault` is that you are scanning the input `B` as a string instead of a character (it is equivalent to `{'B','\0'}`, so it is not just `B`) and you are trying to assign this string into a `char` .

If you want to get a character as input (seems like you want it this way) you must do :

```
scanf ("%c",&grade);
```

The `%c` format specifier is for scanning `char`s, and `&grade` is basically the address of grade.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
However, if you want to get a string as input (i.e. character array in C) , you must define grade like this :

```
char grade [n];
```

(`n` is a number telling the size of array)

and the `scanf` line must be :

```
scanf ("%s",grade);
```

The `%s` format specifier is for getting `string`s (i.e. character arrays in C). The reason why we used `grade` without an address-of (`&`) operator is related with pointers. Because `grade` is already a pointer; we need its value (i.e. the address of the first character of array), not address. Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-in-c-and-c-set-1-introduction-arithmetic-and-array/) link for better understanding. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/14036413) post after ensuring you've understood the logic of pointers.

Note : This is a self study question. Avoid getting downvoted as possible.

Comment: hmm, now i seem to behaving a problem where it exits the program before i can even answer it. like this                                                                                                                    
Enter your grade: Your grade is